What's happening with Rococo Contracts?
The last block was 97 hours ago


Contracts has been historically maintained by Parity. While I cannot really speak to its status I just wanted to drop here that I am part of the team maintaining Pop Network, now running its testnet on Paseo. I'll invite you and all other ink! developers to give it a try!
One can easily onboard tokens to the network with a combination of paseo's faucet and pop network onboarding ui https://onboard.popnetwork.xyz/.

All Rococo Parachains are currently not producing blocks. We are going to fix this, but Rococo will be eventually deprecated for Paseo.
If possible, use Paseo already.

Thanks for the tip.

Context: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/4559
